# How to filter one model by another if it doesnt have relation

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have 2 models and model `ObjectList` has m2m field to `CounterParty` but i need to show info from CounterParty model filtered by object

How am i suppose to do it?

```
class CounterParty(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Наименование')


class ObjectList(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Наименование')

    contractor_guid = models.ManyToManyField(CounterParty, related_name='object_contractor',default=None, blank=True)
```

I know this is not right but it should look like this

```
object = ObjectList.objects.get(id=1)
a = CounterParty.objects.filter(object_contractor=object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt is correct: you use the `related_name` to query in reverse. The fact that it is not defined on the model is not relevant: queries can be done in all directions. If you however don't need the `ObjectList`, you can just use:

```
CounterParty.objects.filter(object_contractor__id=1)
```